# how download Zend_Jabber library?

Tags: zend-framework, xmpp, zend-framework-modules

I've downloaded Zend framework, but the ZEND_JABBER library isn't included. How can I download it? (http://framework.zend.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=30641)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That page is a proposal for a class for ZF but it doesn't appear to have ever been completed.  It never was part of ZF 1 anyway.  There don't appear to be any packages for ZF2 that handle Jabber at the moment either.  The code for that proposal is available on [google code](http://code.google.com/p/phpjabberlib/downloads/list) but hasn't been changed since 2007 and may be incomplete.

[xmpphp](http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/) looks like a promising library for xmpp as does [JAXL](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL).  There are also many other [php jabber clients](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+jabber+client) that should all work with your ZF app.